# GCM issues on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I tried to implement `GCM` for android. It successfully received message on phones with `android L` and below (except Xiaomi phone). But it didn't work on phones with `android M` (Nexus 5 and 6).

I think it is due to the permissions on android M, as I encountered an error related with permissions. Would that be the issue ? Is there something else I should take care of when implementing `GCM` on android M ?

Let me know, thanks!

I followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) to build android-side GCM (8.4.0).

Comment: Post exception. 
Try it two ways: 
1 Grant permissions through Settings-> app->yourapp-> permission
2 Disable all permissions 
Check in which case whats the result and post it to us alos :)

Comment: I don't think issue is with your GCM/Web service. You might have to modify app in case device has MOS, redirect to settings to grant permissions or have an activity based on permission check to allow permissions to launch app .

Comment: which settings i must change? on web service side or android side?

Comment: android MOS device side.

Comment: i'm sorry, but what is MOS? i never heard that before :(

Comment: Marshmallow operating system device

Comment: Please post your logcat error message. It would be helpful.

Comment: no error from logcat because data succesfully sent from server but devices didn't receive it

Comment: If you look at the documentation there is a behavior change for Android M on  how to handle [notifications](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-notifications). This could be a good start for you if ever you missed anything in the code of your receiving end.

Comment: Check for dangerous permissions on developers.android website. If your app needs any permission among them, you need to go through Runtime Permission Request tutorial.